# Pivot group multi column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

In SQL, how can I merge multiple columns into one column with multiple rows?
Example:

```
name  |  age  |  gender
------+-------+---------
John  |   20  |    M
Jill  |   21  |    F
Exam  |   22  |    M
```

I want to get this table:

```
Exam  |  John |  Jill
------+-------+---------
22    |   21  |   20
M     |   F   |   M
```

Comment: What's DBMS did you use?

Comment: @D-Shih: I'm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this.

Use two `PIVOT` query with `UNION ALL` to combine them

```
SELECT CAST(Exam AS VARCHAR(10)) Exam,
       CAST(Jill AS VARCHAR(10)) Jill,
       CAST(John AS VARCHAR(10)) John
FROM
(
    select age,name
    from T
) as x
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(Age) FOR name IN ([Exam],[John],[Jill])
)AS P1
UNION ALL
SELECT Exam,Jill,John FROM
(
    select name,gender
    from T
) as x
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(gender) FOR name IN ([Exam],[John],[Jill])
)AS P1
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a437d/6*

Comment: My data using utf-8 of column name. How to convert column Jill? CAST(Jill AS VARCHAR(10)) Jill -> I mean utf-8

Comment: I known how to use your script. Thank you so much. You saved my life.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a single query -- basically unpivot and conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when v.name = 'Exam' then v.val end) as exam,
       max(case when v.name = 'John' then v.val end) as john,
       max(case when v.name = 'Jill' then v.val end) as jill
from t cross apply
     (values (t.name, cast(t.age as varchar(10)), 1),
             (t.name, t.gender, 2)
     ) v(name, val, which)
group by which;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a437d/20) is the SQL Fiddle.

You can convert the values to whatever character type you like for compatibility among the values.  You want to put numeric values and strings in the same column, so they have to have the same type.